# error message at vagrant start with puppet provisioning

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I wrote an automized puppet file for the installation with Vagrant.

It's just for a fast installation for a apache web server (with PHP5, MySQL)
and atm it is as simple as possible for the beginning.

Every time I start up my Vagrant I get these messages and couldn't interpret
by myself:

```
←[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Lamp/Package[php5]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' t
o 'present'←[0m
←[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Lamp/Package[mysql-client]/ensure: ensure changed 'p
urged' to 'present'←[0m
←[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Lamp/Package[mysql-server]/ensure: ensure changed 'p
urged' to 'present'←[0m
←[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Lamp/Package[apache2]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged
' to 'present'←[0m
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an error at all.
It just says, that the state of those packages has changed from purged to present.

- purged = not installed
- present = installed

It just means, the package was installed successfully.